# Spring @JsonSubTypes with very different abstract class structure

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I'm trying to receive a time object from an HTTP request. The following requests are possible, each of which should generate a different class.

```
time: {
    type: relative          | absolute,
    value: string(eg:L24H)  | {startTime: xxxx, endTime: xxxx}
}
```

The class generated based on `type`. Hope this part is self explanatory.
I made the following structure with an abstract and made two classes extent it.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use =Id.NAME,
    include = As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type",
    visible = true
)
@JsonSubTypes({

    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RelativeSearchTimeRange.class, name = "relative"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AbsoluteSearchTimeRange.class, name = "absolute")


})

public abstract class SearchTimeRange<V> {
  private String type;

  private V value;

  private Time time;

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }


  public V getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(V value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Things **work fine in the first implementation**:

```
public class RelativeSearchTimeRange extends SearchTimeRange<RelativeSearchTimeRange.RelativeTime> {

  enum RelativeTime {
    L24H, L3D;
  }

  private RelativeTime value;


  @Override public void setValue(RelativeTime value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @Override public RelativeTime getValue() {
    return value;
  }
```

But the second one fails:

```
public class AbsoluteSearchTimeRange extends SearchTimeRange<AbsoluteSearchTimeRange> {

  private Time value;

public void setValue(Time value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public AbsoluteSearchTimeRange(Long startTime, Long endTime) {
    value = new Time(startTime, endTime);
  }

  @Override public Time getTime() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

Error: `Could not read document: Can not construct instance of io.redlock.common.dal.AbsoluteSearchTimeRange, problem: null`

The Time class looks like this (with proper getters and setters):

```
public class Time {
  long startTime;
  long endTime;
}
```

What am I missing in `AbsoluteTimeRange`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure **why** it worked, but I had to add a default constructor to the `AbsoluteTimeRange` class.

Most welcome if someone can clarify further.